# how to split a unicode string into list

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, unicode-string

I have the following code:

```
stru = "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"
strlist = stru.decode("utf-8").split()
print strlist[0]
```

my output is :

```
۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹
```

But when i use:

```
print strlist[1]
```

I get the following `traceback`:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**My question**  is, how can I `split` my `string`? Of course, remember I get my `string` from a `function`, consider it's a `variable`?

Comment: list comprehension maybe? `strlist = [s for s in stru.decode('utf-8')]`

Comment: I would think a unicode string is a unique problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `split()` method by default splits on whitespace. Therefore, `strlist` is a list that contains the whole string in `strlist[0]`, and one single element.

If you want a list with one element for each unicode codepoint you can do transform it into a list in different ways:

- Function: `list(stru.decode("utf-8"))`
- List comprension: `[item for item in stru.decode("utf-8")]`
- Not convert at all. Do you really need a list? You can iterate over the unicode string just like over any other sequence type (`for character in stru.decode("utf-8"):` ...)

Answer (score 14):

1. You don't need to.

   ```
   >>> print u"۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"[1]
   ۱
   ```
2. If you still *want* to...

   ```
   >>> list(u"۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹")
   [u'\u06f0', u'\u06f1', u'\u06f2', u'\u06f3', u'\u06f4', u'\u06f5', u'\u06f6', u'\u06f7', u'\u06f8', u'\u06f9']
   ```

Comment: +1 no need to make a list, you're right

Answer (score 6):

You can do this

```
list(stru.decode("utf-8"))
```